# Ionic & Angular - ion-select null value is not recognized

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I have an issue in my ionic 4 application with angular 8 (incl. reactive forms) by rendering an [`ion-select`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select):

Unfortunately my `null` value option is not recognized as selected value for the `ion-select` even though the value (null) for the ion-select is present as possible `ion-select-option`.

My Component looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
    public formGroup;
    public types = [
        {
            value: null,
            title: 'All'
        },
        {
            value: 'Type-1',
            title: 'Type 1'
        },
        {
            value: 'Type-2',
            title: 'Type 2'
        }
    ];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            type: [null]
        });
    }
}
```

The template for this component looks like this:

```
<ion-content>
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label position="floating">Type</ion-label>
              <ion-select formControlName="type" interface="popover">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">
                  {{ type.title }}
                </ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

A workaround by using a `[placeholder]` on the `ion-select` for the null-value is not useful for my scenario, as I'd like to have the `null` option still available for the user even if an other option is selected before.

Is there a solution for this problem or am I doing something wrong in combination with ionic4/reactive forms?

Comment: In addition: If I only set the default value for the type as empty string, the according option is rendered as selected. `types[0].value = '';` - But this is also just a workaround and not the final solution in my opinion.

Comment: Out of curiosity asking, why cant you try like this? 
public types = [{value: 'all', title: 'All' },.....]; 
And In Constructor
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            type: ['all']
        });

Comment: @GangadharGandi This would be a working solution. But in my scenario I'd like to have the `null` value for later `formGroup.getRawValue()` and form submission as the server api only accepts the `null` value for the "all types" option. Of course I could easily map the payload before form submission.

Comment: If it was the case, Send null if the option selected is equal to 'all' when you are submitting form

Comment: @GangadharGandi Yes exactly, but this is also a workaround and not the elegant solution.

Comment: How about this? public types = [{value: 'null', title: 'All' },.....]; And In Constructor this.formGroup = this.fb.group({ type: ['null'] });

Comment: Well `'null'` is not `null`. Everything not equal to `null` is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I tried a workaround with compareWith function:

```
<ion-select ... [compareWith]="compareWithFn">

public compareWithFn(value1, value2) {
    // value1 option value, value2 - control value
    if (value1 === null && !value2) {
        return true;
    }
    return value1 === value2;
}
```

That helped me to have the 'All' option selected.

Comment: compareWithFn does not trigger when you set null value in binded (using ngModel) variable